# When create Android apk those apk crash after install real device crash

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, eas

Please suggest any solution.

When I create apk in eas-cli my apk crashes.

Step 1: When run npm expo-doctor

```
✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
✖ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK
```

> Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~7.2.2
> Found invalid:
> @expo/config-plugins@7.3.1
> (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
> Advice: Upgrade dependencies that are using the invalid package versions.

One or more checks failed, indicating possible issues with the project.

PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\app> npm ls @expo/config-plugins@7.3.1
pesttest@1.0.0 C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\app
└─┬ expo-router@2.0.8
└─┬ expo-linking@6.0.0
└─┬ expo-constants@14.5.1
└─┬ @expo/config@8.2.1
└── @expo/config-plugins@7.3.1